# question mark in request

Tags: javascript, ajax, fastapi

I have FastAPI request and with a text input of "how are you?" and it works on the swagger page without issue:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://xxxx.cloud/ai-chatbot/extract_text?q=how%20are%20you%3F' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -d ''
```

The issue is that when I pass "how are you?" on the ui, through the following JS code, I get 422 Unprocessable Entity. Here is the request:

```
var data = {
            "msg": msg+" d",
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}/ai-chatbot/extract_text?q=${data.msg+' d'}/1`,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            
            success: function (res) {
                var res = JSON.parse(res);
                drawMessage(res)
            },
            error: function (err) {
                if (err.desc == null)
                    err.desc = "Something went wrong!"
                toastr.error(err.desc)
            }
        })
```

what's the issue that the server side works well but the request on the UI gives 422 error?

the issue is due to having question mark at the end of request. I tried adding space but it didn't work.

Comment: Unless the value of `msg` in your JS code is supposed to be URL-encoded already, then that's likely to be the issue - that you are inserting this value into the URL, _without_ encoding it.

Comment: @CBroe How do you think I should change the code to get a result?

Comment: The body of the 422 error will tell you what is missing from your request.

Comment: Use: ```q=${encodeURIComponent(data.msg+' d')}/1```

Comment: @Barmar it didn't work...the same error.

Comment: In the `curl` command you don't send any data, the query is only in the URL. Why are you sending it with `$.ajax`?

Comment: @Barmar =how%20are%20you%3F is the data.

Comment: The `data:` option to `$.ajax` corresponds to the `-d` option in `curl`. That's blank.

Comment: Why do you concatenate `d` to the message? You're appending it twice when you do `data.msg + ' d'`, since you already added the `d` when you created `data`.